# Connecting to database in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 for web and I'm following this tutorial : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791740/Using-AngularJs-ASP-NET-MVC-Web-API-and-EntityFram which specifies this connection to connect ot the db:

```
<add name="MainDb" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=SimpleTaskSystemDb; Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

but when I run Update-Database I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I've also finished the Music Store app which is working fine and the connection there is different:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|MusicStore.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

I tried a similar connection string but that didn't work either.

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider
>   is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application
>   config file.

However the Music Store app.config file does not reference System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 but I added it to this app anyway and then I get back to my original error.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which Edition of sql server are you using,

Comment: That's what I'm unsure of. I'm using whatever version comes with Express 2013 for Web but I can't find that info anywhere. When I run SQLMCD -L I get this: 

    Servers:
    ;UID:Login ID=?;PWD:Password=?;Trusted_Connection:Use Integrated Security=?;
*APP:AppName=?;*WSID:WorkStation ID=?;

Comment: Please follow my detailed answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some of the sample connection strings I have described every connection string with full details

**For Local Sql server (BuildIn Sql Server Express into Visual Studio).**

```
 For Sql Server instance which comes default with visual studio you can use following connection string  

 <connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**For Sql Server Which Has been installed seperately such as Evaluation Edition etc**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=YourPCName-PC\ServerInstanceName;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**For CompactEdition of Sql server you can use provider name as**

providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I used the first string but can you explain why using 'localhost' or './SQLexpress' as mentioned in the tutorial didn't work? Also since my MusicStore app is working with providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" does that mean I have 2 versions installed? See the screen shot I added....

Comment: Wellcome.I have not worked with Visual Studio Express so I cann't tell you this why is this working.I work with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.I am also working on SPA(Single Page apps) stay in touch plz

Comment: Its seems as you have both edition installed or may be visual studio express 2013 is designed to work with both Compact Edition and Express Edition.

Comment: The strange thing is that Update-Database ran successfully and inserted my seed data but I can't find the database anywhere in SQL Server Object Explorer.

Comment: Ya the key here is in the differences of the Data Source for Local DB vs. SQL Express Hosted DBs Locally.  It's confusing to me after having only used SQL Express for 7 years... I think I like the LocalDB stuff but am not sure yet.

Comment: Refresh Sql Server then once again run the Update-Database command then see once again.I will suggest you to work with Evalution edition etc rather than express edition these are always problematics.